# 443 Forbidden, how to use https with Django

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, wsgi

Port 443 has been forbidden, so I have to use other port for https. I've tried Port 2408, and the WSGI configure file as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCmOj.png)

Using command : netstat -lnp | grep , it shows the Port 2048 is listened by httpd，but I still cant access to the site. How should I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: the port is 2048. port number is consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem LOL.

if port 443 not available, port 80 is ok, and the configure file is just like the image i post.

one thing should be noticed that when a browser want to access to the site, the url should be changed. It concerns about the protocol and port, and here we use http protocol and 80 port.

Normally, if we just want to view http protocol site, just input the url, like: 
www.example.com, or even use example.com.

if the server make a redirection from http://www.example.com to htts://www.exmaple.com， the url input above is ok.

Above situation is under the circumstance that 443 port is open, but 443 port is not open, and no listen service running on httpd, HOW I SHOULD DO ?

you must input  https://www.example.com:80. It means the service is listening to the port 80 and using https.

Therefore, it's not about the server, but the client and browser as well, which should give more attention.